# How to use pairwiseCI with a mixed model forumla (lmer(y~x))?

Tags: r

I want to use pairwiseCI to calculate the CI of ratio of two normally distributed variables as following:

```
pairwiseCI(
   formula, data, by = NULL,
   alternative = "two.sided", conf.level = 0.95,
   method = "Param.ratio", control = NULL, ...)
```

The question is: my model is a mixed model using `lmer(y~1+treatment+(1|group)),` but the argument formula must have the structure 'response ~ treatment' in pairwiseCI function. So how can I incorporate this mixed model into the format of formula `y~x` in pairwiseCI function?

Comment: perhaps you want to run `confint(...)` on your lmer object? See `?confint.merMod` I do not see the connection to `pairwiseCI`

Comment: Question seems to be confused. What are the "two normally distributed variables"?

Comment: Thanks for your comments! I have a mixed model for example height~treatment+(1|location), treatment is a fixed effect with three levels A, B, C, location is a random effect. Based on this model, I can get lsmeans of height in each treatment group. The I want to compare the lsmeans in treatment group A with treatment group B. Usually we calculate A-B and the according CI for A-B. But now, I want to calculate the CI of A/B, the ratio. That is why I want to use pairwiseCI. But it seems that pairwiseCI can not deal with mixed model. @ckluss

Comment: Thanks! I think I did't tell a clear background of my case. Sorry for that.

Comment: I have a mixed model for example height~treatment+(1|location), treatment is a fixed effect with three levels A, B, C, location is a random effect. Based on this model, I can get lsmeans of height in each treatment group. The I want to compare the lsmeans in treatment group A with treatment group B. Usually we calculate A-B and the according CI for A-B. But now, I want to calculate the CI of A/B, the ratio. That is why I want to use pairwiseCI. But it seems that pairwiseCI can not deal with mixed model. Sorry I didn't clarify that. @ BondedDust

Comment: Analysis of ratio outcomes is a complex topic. It's not at all clear that you have the proper background to begin such an effort. Why not assemble all the details, delete this question and repost on CrossValidated.com